# import {fn1} from 'lib' vs import fn1 from 'lib'

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, lodash

I am importing a few functions from lodash and my coworker tells me that it's better to import each function separately than to import them as a group.

Current method:

```
import {fn1, fn2, fn3} from 'lodash';
```

Preferred method:

```
import fn1 from 'lodash/fn1';
import fn2 from 'lodash/fn2';
import fn3 from 'lodash/fn3';
```

Her reasoning is that latter imports less code, as it won't import the entire lodash library.

Is that the case?

Comment: I think you misunderstood: Preferred method is `import fn1 from 'lodash/fn1';
import fn2 from 'lodash/fn2';
import fn3 from 'lodash/fn3';`

Comment: Thanks. Changed the question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want (and what is preferred) is called [tree shaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking):

> Tree-shaking is the process of
>   removing unused code during the bundle process.

The correct way to do this and utilize the tree shaking is:

```
import foo from 'lodash/foo' // <-- only import `foo`
```

This **will not** tree-shake:

```
import { foo } from 'lodash'
```

**nor** will, obviously this:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

Support for this syntax was implemented in `Lodash v4`.

You can read [more here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/tree-shaking/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifying response! I have previously only heard of tree-shaking, but didn't know how it would apply to anything I did. Now I do.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sources I can find, `import x from y;` imports the default export from `y`, calling it `x` in your file.

So your preferred method is importing the default export 3 times, with 3 different variable names...

Is the preferred method working in production?

Sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-modules-for-beginners-56939088f7d9

Comment: There is also [this post](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark/) (with it's clickbait title) which goes into detail around the pros and cons of each approach and benchmarks too. Based on the evidence presented in this post it would seem that there are size/performance benefits to be had by importing the modules one by one, if you're happy with the tradeoff (a long import block in your js file).

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that `import {fn1, fn2, fn3} from 'lodash';` is the correct way to import different exports of module, however, I think it could be better to use this way

```
    import {
      fn1, 
      fn2, 
      fn3
    } from 'lodash';
```

Since it is easier to remove any of them if it no longer requires

Comment: I think you should explain that this is actually using destructuring to extract those items from the default exports.

Comment: @Barmar this syntax doesn't access the `default` export, nor any of its members.

Comment: That's the same thing it's just with line breaks.